# How do I install in expert mode on an old 512MB laptop and wireless problem

Tags: 12.04, wireless, system-installation

Intial screen in 12.04 LTS live DVD help references <kbd>F7</kbd> & <kbd>F8</kbd> menu options that are not there. During install I guess it couldn't find the drivers for the LINKSYS WPC54G ver 3 pcmcia card and sent me to a site `http://wireless.kernal.org/en/users/b43#devicefirmware` that now is some sort of religious site.

Trying to install on old Dell C800s with 512MB RAM to give to some underprivileged kids.

Have tried turning off pcmcia during install as one place suggested, but now that I know it sees the wireless card, assume that is not why I always get a "critical error, install cannot continue"

Also wondering at the online help always referencing floppy disks and then there's the install in expert mode, that might give me some more control and ability to figure out what is going wrong, but it never tells you how to do start the install in that mode.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I'm sorry to hear about the trouble you are having.  However your post reads more like a stream of conscious rant than a question--as such, it is unlikely to get any useful answers (see [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2764/63478)).  I would suggest editing and reformatting your question so it is clear exactly what problems you are facing--and including as many details about the problems as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the **alternate install** CD, which is recommended for old/Low memory systems and will let you go into expert mode.

Also, it's **kernEl.org** NOT kernAl.org in that link for the b43 drivers you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Thanks IZX. I noticed the spelling error later, though that doesn't seem to be the problem anyway, even though I found that those drivers are missing on the 12.04LT. ademwolf, if I knew the problem, I would have been more clear, but there is nothing telling you what it's trying to do when it stops, so all I have is "Urecoverable Error, cannot continue will load the Live session now"

Answer (score 0):

Actually,"http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/b43#devicefirmware" its not out of date and leads me to a useful website. That website helped me to got my usb modem dongle working. But like Izx said, try the alternate install cd.

Best regards,

Comment: Thanks to all, downloaded the 11.10 alternate cd and installed fine with a few exceptions that I seem to need to fix that I found fixes for elsewhere. Problem now is one of those fixes is to modify XORG.CONFIG and I can't find it in the X11 directory as the fix describes, is it hidden, and if so how do I unhide it to modify it.